# How to default a value in subquery result?

Tags: mysql, subquery, oracle12c

Hopefully this is a simple one but I am most likely over complicating this for myself. Purpose of this code is to find previous operation name within a specified list of operations that is still open and returning it. If it's closed to say 'CLOSED'.

So far I'm using subquery to get the correct operation name, as expected I'm getting some null results which indicates to me that operation is closed. I wanted to wrap my subquery into a case statement to say something along the lines of CASE WHEN it's null then 'CLOSED' else operation_name end.

```
(select work_center_no 
  from shop_order_operation  
  where order_no = so.order_no 
  and release_no = so.release_no 
  and sequence_no = so.sequence_no 
  and work_center_no in ('CNC','EXPF','LS3M','LS4M','LS6M','PLAS','SAW','TBPL','EXSAW')
  and oper_status_code in ('Released','In Process') order by operation_no fetch first 1 row only )
```

Above is my subquery. Hope this makes sense.

Thanks!
K

Comment: *I wanted to wrap my subquery into a case statement to say something along the lines of CASE WHEN it's null then 'CLOSED' else operation_name end.* Do it in subquery: `(select COALESCE(work_center_no, 'CLOSED') AS work_center_no from shop_order_operation ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nicely default a value using [IFNULL](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-ifnull/), just change your `select` clause to this:

```
select IFNULL(work_center_no, 'CLOSED')
```

Comment: Very nicely indeed! Occam's razor!

"the simplest solution is most likely the right one"

Comment: @KasiaWichrowska you are welcome. As far as I remember, Occam's razor is a philosophical approach which opposes unnecessary hypothesis. In science there is the so-called null hypothesis, which is the best hypothesis to choose if one is forced to assume something (which should be avoided when possible, of course). The null hypothesis is the case which is the closest to the complete lack of assumption.

Comment: It's often paraphrased as in your comment, but there is a slight, but relevant difference between the two. The paraphrased version assumes that simplification will get us closer to the right solution, while the original (and in my opinion more precise) version does not assume that simplicity will likely yield better understanding/solution, it just states that making it more complicated should be justified when done and one should avoid complicating it when unnecessary. However, it's very good and refreshing to hear philosophical remarks from fellow programmers.

Comment: My mind was blown first time I heard it. I'm enjoying reading your feedback, every day is a learning day! Thanks for that! :)